# Unable to view SQLite database table data in WPF gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I've created a database using DB Browser for SQLite which looks like this
[image: database]

Now, I'm trying to load this data to a DataGrid in my WPF app.

My app.config file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=.\TestDB.db;Version=3;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="SQLiteTestWPF.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SQLiteTestWPF" Height="300" Width="500"
>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="217" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="73,33,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="364">
            
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="40" Binding="{Binding ID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Width="100" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Width="100" Binding="{Binding LastName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Age}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            
            
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Codebihind

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Data.SQLite.Generic;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SQLiteTestWPF
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            refreshdata();
        }
        
        public void refreshdata()
        {

            using(SQLiteConnection conn= new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=.\TestDB.db;"))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("Select * from Test", conn);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                
                SQLiteDataAdapter adap = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
                
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");
                adap.Fill(dt);
                
                dataGrid1.ItemsSource=dt.DefaultView;
                adap.Update(dt);
                
                conn.Close();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program I get the below error !!

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The invocation of the
> constructor on type 'SQLiteTestWPF.Window1' that matches the specified
> binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line
> position '9'. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
> 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I'm new to SQLite and struggling to figure out how do I fix this ? Please help :(

Note: I've downloaded the file `sqlite-netFx45-binary-x64-2012-1.0.115.5` from the [SQLite website](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) and used the 2 dll's `System.Data.SQLite.dll` and `SQLite.Interop.dll` in my project.

Comment: Any reason why you do not reference the nuget package?

Comment: @SirRufo I did not use a nuget package. I just downloaded the files from SQLite's website and added the the 2 dll's mentioned in my post.

Comment: @SirRufo Now that you mentioned it I've installed the nuget package `System.Data.SQLite.Core version 1.0.115.5` and after building and running now I get the error `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'SQLiteTestWPF.Window1' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error
no such table: Test`

Comment: Well I've actually installed `stub.system.data.sqlite.core.netframework.1.0.115.5` & not `System.Data.SQLite.Core version 1.0.115.5`. I'm unable to install `System.Data.SQLite.Core version 1.0.115.5` most likely cause I'm using net 4.5.

Comment: When the given file does not exists, then sqlite will create it (but of course it is empty without any tables or data). Guess you are running into this ;o) - Check the result of [`Path.GetFullPath("./TestDB.db")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netframework-4.8#system-io-path-getfullpath(system-string)) and see if that match with the path you expect. The main problem is, that you are using a relative path (relative to the current directory, which also can change during the application lifetime)

Comment: @SirRufo You were right. It is working now. BTW if the database is in the `Release` folder and I share that folder to my client or whatever will the `Path.GetFullPath` approach work in that case ? Thanks :)

Comment: The `Path.GetFullPath` "approach" was only for you to check if you are working with the file you expected. You should never use a path relative to the current directory unless you really want that (in most cases you do not). My applications store data in different locations then the application exe stays (as microsoft recommends). There are `%AppData%` or `%LocalAppData%` or sometimes `ProgramData%`. But you have to know about the concepts of this folders and when to use which for your application.